# Stuck with LDU-factorization of a matrix where D should contain zeros

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition

I thought that L-D-U- factorization of a square matrix (L=lower triangular factor, D=diagonal factors, U=upper triangular factor) was always possible and meaningful even if I encounter zeros on the diagonal factor D. But my algorithm is not correct in that cases in that the resulting factors do not reproduce the source.
Let $$  M = \begin{bmatrix} 
    1&    2&    3&    4&    5\\
    2&    4&    6&    8&    0\\
    3&    6&    9&    2&    5\\
    4&    8&    2&    6&    0\\
    5&    0&    5&    0&    5
     \end{bmatrix}$$
which is just the top-left of the basic $10 \times 10$ multiplication-table (modulo $10$). It has full rank; but in the naive LDU-algorithm one would assign zeros to some entries of D because zeros occur in the top-left element of the intermediate matrices of the iteration. If I do that, I get LDU-components
$$\small L=\begin{bmatrix} 
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\ 
 2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\ 
 3 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0  \\ 
 4 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0  \\ 
 5 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 1  \\ 
 \end{bmatrix} 
 D= \begin{bmatrix} 
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\ 
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\ 
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\ 
 0 & 0 & 0 & -10 & 0  \\ 
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 20  \end{bmatrix} 
 U=\begin{bmatrix} 
 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5  \\ 
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\ 
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0  \\ 
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 2  \\ 
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1  \\ 
 \end{bmatrix}$$
and if I put them together they don't reproduce the source M:
$$ \text{chk}=L \cdot D \cdot U = \small \begin{bmatrix} 
 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ 
 2 & 4 & 6 & 8 & 10 \\ 
 3 & 6 & 9 & 12 & 15 \\ 
 4 & 8 & 12 & 6 & 0 \\ 
 5 & 10 & 15 & 0 & 5
 \end{bmatrix}$$
The problem is not, that the matrix-rank of M were not sufficient - Pari/GP gives the inverse and even the diagonalization.

> Q: Can this be repaired? Can a meaningful L-D-U-decomposition be given?

Of course, if a general argument exists why and when invertible/diagonalizable matrices cannot be LU or LDU-decomposed I'd like to learn that, too.

Comment: $l = \left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 \frac{4}{5} & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 \frac{3}{5} & \frac{3}{4} & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 \frac{2}{5} & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{2}{3} & 1 & 0 \\
 \frac{1}{5} & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{2} & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$, $d = \left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 5 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 8 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & \frac{15}{2} & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{20}{3} & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 5 \\
\end{array}
\right)$

Comment: $u = \left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 1 & -\frac{1}{4} & \frac{3}{4} & -\frac{1}{2} \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & -\frac{1}{3} & \frac{2}{3} \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -\frac{1}{2} \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$

Comment: Notice what you get when you multiply $LDU$? There is a Permutation. Since we can find an PLU decomposition, we can find an LDU decomposition, but we have a permutation matrix $A = PLU$. Sorry for the quick answer - time to run to work. Might be interested in: http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0506382v1.pdf

Comment: $p = \left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$

Comment: Ah, that arxiv-article seems to cover my question exactly. Thank you

Comment: @variable: if you put the arxiv-link in your comment into an aswer I'd give that the accept-mark. Surprisingly in yor solution we don't have $l=u^t$ although $M$ is symmetric.

Comment: Done. Please also see the nice corollary from Horn and Johnson I linked in addition. See all of Section 3.5. Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at my comments, you can see a permuted solution and the details of an $A = LDU$ factorization for your matrix.

This nice write-up includes the [*Necessary And Sufficient Conditions For
Existence of the LU Factorization of an
Arbitrary Matrix*](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0506382v1.pdf) and includes the answers to your question.

Lastly, here is a nice [*Corollary*](https://books.google.com/books?id=O7sgAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA218&lpg=PA218&dq=matrix+horn+johnson+ldu&source=bl&ots=lUPbrffqf5&sig=GgvVYWKHehJOnoGC3gGaj97qL0Q&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwilw7m6i5bKAhUP6mMKHTwqDN0Q6AEIODAE#v=onepage&q=matrix%20horn%20johnson%20ldu&f=false) in the Matrix Analysis book by Horn and Johnson. Worth perusing all of Section $3.5$ in addition to the corollary on the $LDU$ factorization.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do this by pivoting. In the second step of the LU or LDU decomposition, your matrix becomes
M = \begin{bmatrix} 
    1&    2&    3&    4&    5\\
    0&    0&    0&    0&    -10\\
    0&    0&    0&    -10&    -10\\
    0&    0&    -10&    -10&    -20\\
    0&    -10&    -10&    -20&    -20
     \end{bmatrix}

You will then need to multiply it by a permutation matrix $P=$
 \begin{bmatrix} 
    1&    0&    0&    0&    0\\
    0&    0&    0&    0&    1\\
    0&    0&    0&    1&    0\\
    0&    0&    1&    0&    0\\
    0&    1&    0&    0&    0
     \end{bmatrix}
Then your lower triangular matrix $L_P$ becomes $PLP^{-1}$, and the $LDU$ decomposition formula is $PA=L_PDU$. Refer to [this article](http://www4.ncsu.edu/~kksivara/ma505/handouts/lu-pivot.pdf) about LU with pivoting.

Your $L$ looks almost correct, but there isn't a $2$ in the 5th row and 4th column. The $U$ should be 
 \begin{bmatrix} 
    1&    2&    3&    4&    5\\
    0&    1&    1&    2&    2\\
    0&    0&    1&    1&    2\\
    0&    0&    0&    1&    1\\
    0&    0&    0&    0&    1
     \end{bmatrix}
And $D=$
 \begin{bmatrix} 
    1&    0&    0&    0&    0\\
    0&    -10&    0&    0&    0\\
    0&    0&    -10&    0&    0\\
    0&    0&    0&    -10&    0\\
    0&    0&    0&    0&    -10
\end{bmatrix}

Comment: Pivoting... *that* was the idea. Thank you very much. Meanwhile I've tried this myself manually and got a slightly different result: $L$ is no more triangular. (I'll put my new solution into a separate answer). This is similar to your solution: we get a LDU-solution of  $M =( P^{-1} L  Q) * D * (Q^{-1}  U  P) $   with two different permutations $P$ and $Q$ *(the symmetry in the result is because $M$ is symmetric itself)*. So apparently we have a case which is *"not truely LDU-decomposable"* and I'd like to get a term for this property of some set of matrices $M$. (cntd...)

Comment: For non-*diagonalizable* matrices we say they have a *Jordan-form*  and know this form for instance by evaluation of multiplicity of eigenvalues. Can we point out some property in this/in a similar/analoguous sense?

Comment: @GottfriedHelms: The LU decomposition with pivoting is usually done with the form $PA=LU$. So after the permutation $PA$, the process of $LU$ would not involve pivoting any more. This avoids the issue that $L, U$ becomes non-triangular. Do you have a resource of your result? For the other question, I didn't quite understand what you meant. What kind of property?

Comment: KittyL: "...resource..." hmm, I've just done it by hand with my matrix-calculator. Do you mean the script? Or do you mean some reference?

Comment: @GottfriedHelms: Never mind then. I was just seeing if your method is in the literature.

Comment: I see, thank you for all your effort. Sometimes a small idea can help to step over a big stone... (perhaps even only: ... around it)

Comment: I've just added the code with which I computed the things manually (with my MatMate-utility) into my answer. I guess it is easily translatable into Matlab et al. to reproduce all the interim-results.

Answer (score 1):

What I got by some manual pivoting is the following half-baked result:
$$ L = U^t =  \begin{bmatrix} 
     1&     0&     0&     0&     0\\
     2&     1&     0&     0&     \frac12\\
     3&     1&     1&     1&     \frac12\\
     4&     2&     0&     1&     1\\
     5&     0&     0&     0&     1
     \end{bmatrix} $$

$$ D = \begin{bmatrix}
       1&5&10& -10&-20
     \end{bmatrix} $$
and indeed
$$ M = L \cdot D \cdot U $$ 
However, $L$ and thus $U=L^t$ are not triangular and thus this is not a true LDU-decomposition.
Of course I could permute $L$ and $D$, but I had to permute then not only the columns but also the rows in $L$ and $D$, so denoting the permutations by $P$ and $Q$ I find by this 
$$ P^{-1}\cdot M \cdot P = (P^{-1} \cdot L \cdot Q ) \cdot ( Q^{-1} D Q ) \cdot  (Q^{-1} \cdot U \cdot P ) \\ \text{ or } \\
    M_p = L_p \cdot D_p \cdot U_p = L_p \cdot D_p \cdot L_p^t $$
where the parenthesized expressions are triangular (and incidentally $Q=P$) - but this means on the other hand, it is not really $M$ which I'm decomposing then.

***update***
Here is the triangular solution for $M_p$, taken by permutations:
$$   L_p =  \begin{bmatrix}
       1&       0&       0&       0&       0\\
       5&       1&       0&       0&       0\\
       2&   \frac12&       1&       0&       0\\
       4&       1&       2&       1&       0\\
       3&   \frac12&       1&       1&       1
     \end{bmatrix} \\
 D_p =  \begin{bmatrix}
       1&     -20&       5&     -10&      10
     \end{bmatrix} \\
$$giving the permuted $M_p$ 
$$  M_p = L_p \cdot D_p \cdot L_p^t = \begin{bmatrix}
       1&       5&       2&       4&       3\\
       5&       5&       0&       0&       5\\
       2&       0&       4&       8&       6\\
       4&       0&       8&       6&       2\\
       3&       5&       6&       2&       9
     \end{bmatrix}$$
and my permutation $P$ based on manually selected pivot-elements as
$$ P = Q =   \begin{bmatrix}
       1&       0&       0&       0&       0\\
       0&       0&       1&       0&       0\\
       0&       0&       0&       0&       1\\
       0&       0&       0&       1&       0\\
       0&       1&       0&       0&       0
     \end{bmatrix} $$

---

> Now from the OP the question 2 remains: is that an example where we say: "M is not LDU-decomposable" (like we say that some matrices are "not diagonalizable" and admit only a Jordan-decomposition)? Are there (obvious) criteria for that "non-decomposability" (before actually trying it)?

After a short view it seems, the final answer (also to question 2) is in the article to which @variable has linked to.

***update 2***: ***upps*** that same problem occurs of course in the Cholesky-decomposition of M. The source might be found beforehand by observing, that some eigenvalues of M are negative. A valid cholesky- and LDU-decomposition can then simply be found from the matrix M^2 which has then positive eigenvalues. Hmm - from all this I'll have now to improve my program-code for the LDU as well as for the Cholesky-decomposition. *Oh sigh...*

---

Appendix: code for the example computation

```
// remark: script is for MatMate - language (proprietary)
//                                 Author: Gottfried Helms
macrodef onecolumn
    dx = value( R [piv,piv] )    // piv,piv must point to a nonzero element 
                                 // in the current residual matrix R here! 
                                 // to get the scalar value for the elem. in D
   D[piv,piv] = dx               // fill that value into matrix D
   L[*,piv] = R [*,piv ] /dx     // fill columnvector into matrix L 
   U[piv,*] = R [piv,* ] /dx     // fill rowvector into matrix U
   chk = L * D * U               // check partial reproduction of M
   R   = M - chk                 // make the residual the new version of R
macroend 


// create matrix M with size 5x5
dim=5
M=seq(1,dim)'      // define columnvector 1,2,3,4,5
   M = M *M '      // make M a matrix being the "multiplication table" 
   M = M  mod 10   // make it modulo 10
   M = 1.0 * M     // make it a real instead of an integer matrix
                   // better to work with real matrices

// Start example computation
// initialize ...
D = null(dim,dim)  // empty LDU-factors
L,U = D,D
R = M         // fill the Residualmatrix R for the iterations with M

// ... compute LDU-factors by 5 iterations
piv=1 // piv points to a nonzero diagonal element in the current residual R
macroexec onecolumn 

piv=5 //  I also could have taken =4 here
macroexec onecolumn 

piv=2
macroexec onecolumn 

piv=4
macroexec onecolumn 

piv=3
macroexec onecolumn 

// factors L,D,U are existent now, but are not triangular
// define a permutationmatrix P now by the above "piv"-settings
P = null(dim,dim)
P[1,1],P[5,2],P[2,3],P[4,4],P[3,5]  = 1, 1, 1, 1, 1

// permute matrices, applying "similarity permutations", because P' = P^-1
Lp = P' * L * P   // this gives a lower triangular version of L
Dp = P' * D * P   // Dp is still diagonal, only the diagonalentries are permuted
Up = P' * U * P   // Up is also simply the transpose of Lp
Mp = P' * M * P   // actually, only Mp becomes truly LDU-factored!
chk = Mp - Lp * Dp * Up   // check that difference is indeed zero
```

Comment: If you type this matrix into Matlab using its lu command, it returns you the $P, L, U$, where $L$ and $U$ are the usual triangular matrices, and $P$ is the permutation. And you can check that $PM=LU$. (Of course $D$ is easy to obtain) Since Matlab has this function, I believe it is the usual way people do it when considering the $LU$ decomposition for a matrix that needs pivoting. And notice that $PM$ is just a row-permutated form of $M$, which doesn't change much of the property of $M$.

Comment: So to answer your question, $M$ is still LDU-decomposible. And we don't need Jordan decomposition for it.